# Join big data table with keys tables fast

Tags: php, mysql, sql

this is my second question, so please be patient :)

I have a MySQL database with one big table (`dati`) with this structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dati` (
  `i1` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `i2` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `i3` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `i4` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `i5` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `i6` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `i7` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `i8` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `i9` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `i10` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `totale` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `valore` double DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `i1` (`i1`(20),`i2`(20),`i3`(20),`i4`(20)),
  KEY `i1_2` (`i1`),
  KEY `i2` (`i2`),
  KEY `i3` (`i3`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_swedish_ci;
```

and few smaller tables `i1`-`i4` where the value in field `valore` is linked to the value in `data`.`i<n>` with this structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `i1` (
  `livello` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `valore` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `ordine` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `colore` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `mostrare` double DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `livello` (`livello`),
  KEY `valore` (`valore`),
  KEY `ordine` (`ordine`),
  KEY `mostrare` (`mostrare`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_swedish_ci;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `i2` (
  `livello` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `valore` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `ordine` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `colore` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `mostrare` double DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_swedish_ci;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `i3` (
  `livello` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `valore` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `ordine` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `colore` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `mostrare` double DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_swedish_ci;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `i4` (
  `livello` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `valore` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `ordine` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `colore` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `mostrare` double DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_swedish_ci;
```

Fore every i1-14 I have a selection made by the users, and merged with user's privileges of his allowed values and PHP generates a query in the form:

```
SELECT * FROM `dati`
WHERE (`i1` = 'TARGET|TOTALE')
AND (`i2` = 'BANCHE|ADV AWARENESS SPONTANEA OFFLINE')
AND (`i3` = 'BRAND BANCARI|(NET) BANCOPOSTA')
AND (`i4` = 'ANNO|2014' OR `i4` = 'ANNO|2013')
```

My problem is that I need values for ALL key combinations, even those that have NO entry in the main data table.

I have been suggested that a LEFT JOIN with the i1-i4 tables would get all entries, but I have tried many ways and always get either errors or very slow or never ending queries. How do I join `dati` with `i1`-`i4` in a fast way so that all (selected) key combinations come out (even if no entry is in dati).

So I need to JOIN on dati.i1=i1.valore, dati.i2=i2.valore, etc..

Thanks for any help.
(P.S I will not follow this for a few hours, here is evening now, will get back to it later fromhome)

**EDIT**

At home now, I will try to post some examples that may help.

This is a query of a client script, adapted to the names of these tables, I have no idea why they made it like this, it seems to work somehow, though it looks overly complicated to me,having to generate it with PHP dynamically:

```
select k.i4 , k.i3, k.i1, k.i2, dati.valore, dati.totale as totale, s.base
from (( select * from (
select valore as i4, ordine as ordine_i4 from i4 where valore in ('ANNO|2013','ANNO|2014')) p,
(select valore as i3, ordine as ordine_i3 from i3 where valore in ('BRAND BANCARI|(NET) BANCOPOSTA','BRAND BANCARI|(NET) CONTO ARANCIO/ING DIRECT','BRAND BANCARI|(NET) GRUPPO UNICREDIT','BRAND BANCARI|BANCA MEDIOLANUM')) b,
(select valore as i1, ordine as ordine_i1 from i1 where valore in ('TARGET|INTERNAUTI','TARGET|INTERNAUTI SOCIAL')) t,
(select valore as i2, ordine as ordine_i2 from i2 where valore in ('BANCHE|ADV AWARENESS ONLINE TOTALE','BANCHE|BRAND AWARENESS TOM','BANCHE|BRAND AWARENESS TOTALE','BANCHE|BRAND AWARENESS TOTALE SPONTANEA','BANCHE|NOTIZIABILITA\' OFFLINE','BANCHE|NOTIZIABILITA\' OFFLINE + ONLINE','BANCHE|NOTIZIABILITA\' ONLINE')) a
 ) k left JOIN (
 select * from dati where i4 in ('ANNO|2013','ANNO|2014') And i3 in ('BRAND BANCARI|(NET) BANCOPOSTA','BRAND BANCARI|(NET) CONTO ARANCIO/ING DIRECT','BRAND BANCARI|(NET) GRUPPO UNICREDIT','BRAND BANCARI|BANCA MEDIOLANUM') And i1 in ('TARGET|INTERNAUTI','TARGET|INTERNAUTI SOCIAL') And i2 in ('BANCHE|ADV AWARENESS ONLINE TOTALE','BANCHE|BRAND AWARENESS TOM','BANCHE|BRAND AWARENESS TOTALE','BANCHE|BRAND AWARENESS TOTALE SPONTANEA','BANCHE|NOTIZIABILITA\' OFFLINE','BANCHE|NOTIZIABILITA\' OFFLINE + ONLINE','BANCHE|NOTIZIABILITA\' ONLINE')) as dati
on k.i4=dati.i4 and k.i3=dati.i3 and k.i1=dati.i1 and k.i2=dati.i2 ) left JOIN (select i4, i1, i2, valore as base from dati where i1='TOTALE' ) s on k.i4=s.i4 and k.i1=s.i1 and k.i2=s.i2 ORDER BY k.ordine_i3, k.ordine_i4, k.ordine_i2, k.ordine_i1
```

And some of my **NOT WORKING** trials. This has obvious error somewhere, but I just can't seem to be able to fix it

```
((SELECT * FROM `dati`
    WHERE (`i1` = 'TARGET|TOTALE')
    AND (`i2` = 'BANCHE|ADV AWARENESS SPONTANEA OFFLINE')
    AND (`i3` = 'BRAND BANCARI|(NET) BANCOPOSTA')
    AND (`i4` = 'ANNO|2014')
) aaa )

LEFT JOIN (

    SELECT * FROM (

        (SELECT valore AS `vi1`
        FROM `i1`
        ) `ti1`,

        (SELECT valore AS `vi2`
        FROM `i2`
        ) `ti2`,

        (SELECT valore AS `vi3`
        FROM `i3`
        ) `ti3`,

        (SELECT valore AS `vi4`
        FROM `i4`
        ) `ti4`

    ) bbb
)  ON `ti1`.`vi1` = `dati`.`i1` AND `ti2`.`vi2` = `dati`.`i2`  AND `ti3`.`vi3` = `dati`.`i3`  AND `ti4`.`vi4` = `dati`.`i4`
```

And this one looks cool but just **locks MySQL FOREVER**(!!!):

```
( select * from


( select * from
    (select valore as `vi1`,ordine as `oi1` from `i1`) `ti1`,
    (select valore as `vi2`,ordine as `oi2` from `i2`) `ti2`,
    (select valore as `vi3`,ordine as `oi3` from `i3`) `ti3`,
    (select valore as `vi4`,ordine as `oi4` from `i4`) `ti4`
) allkeys

left join

    (select * from `dati`
        where (`i1`= 'TARGET|TOTALE')
        AND (`i2`= 'BANCHE|ADV AWARENESS SPONTANEA OFFLINE')
        AND (`i3`= 'BRAND BANCARI|(NET) BANCOPOSTA')
        AND (`i4`= 'ANNO|2014') AND (TRUE)
    ) core

on ( `allkeys`.`vi1`=`core`.`i1` and `allkeys`.`vi2`=`core`.`i2`and `allkeys`.`vi3`=`core`.`i3` and `allkeys`.`vi4`=`core`.`i4` ) 
)
```

Comment: This is a terrible database design.

Comment: @Kermit haha, thanks, but the design is not mine and unfortunately I can't modify it (it's the client's), but if you have suggestions I will report them to them

Comment: They don't know how to database. Seriously, [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Comment: @Kermit ok. Yet the pay me for the PHP, any idea about the SQL? :)

Comment: @Kermit I understand what you mean with normalization, they have discussed deeply whether the i1 field had to contain the value or just a key of the i1 table, but in the end the client programmers there have chosen the "unnormalized" approach. The reasons are mostly practical, and space is not a concern and i1-i4 values are not too long, uppercase only labels. Anyway the concept of joining is pretty the same, just imagine the values as keys. If only I could do it..

Comment: Thanks @Dave, only problem I have no idea how to write that! I have plenty of trials that just give errors and some even locked mysql in nowhereland forever...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I opted for a query like this:

```
SELECT `dati`.*
FROM `dati`
RIGHT JOIN `i2` ON `i2`.`valore` = `dati`.`i2`
RIGHT JOIN `i3` ON `i3`.`valore` = `dati`.`i3`
RIGHT JOIN `i4` ON `i4`.`valore` = `dati`.`i4`
WHERE (
`i1` = 'TARGET|INTERNAUTI'
OR `i1` = 'TARGET|INTERNAUTI SOCIAL'
)
AND (
`i2` = 'BANCHE|ADV AWARENESS SPONTANEA ONLINE'
OR `i2` = 'BANCHE|BRAND AWARENESS TOM'
)
AND (
`i3` = 'BRAND BANCARI|(NET) GRUPPO UCXREDIT'
OR `i3` = 'BRAND BANCARI|BANCA MECDIOUM'
)
AND (
`i4` = 'ANNO|2013'
OR `i4` = 'ANNO|2014'
)
AND (

TRUE
)
AND `i2`.`mostrare` =1
AND `i3`.`mostrare` =1
AND `i4`.`mostrare` =1

ORDER BY `i2`.`ordine` asc, `i3`.`ordine` asc, `i4`.`ordine` asc
```

needs indexes on all the i1 - i4 fields of table dati and of valore,ordine and mostrare (=display) of the i1 - i4 tables or it will last forever

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve all these by joins but since your data is high, you have to `index` your table for faster query response. 
You can apply index to that column which is retrieved more often or used again and again in joins. 
Also try to specify the selective column names instead of `*` as that will process your columns faster instead of fetching data from all the columns.

Comment: Yes, I have indexed all the relevant columns, but still the SQL for the query is not clear to me..